# Why does removing content from default.rd.xml in UWP project not have an effect?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, metadata, .net-native

I've commented the line

> `<Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />`

In default.rd.xml, my app became to build two times(!) faster and it's working normally. I've read manual about .rd.xml, it says I have to declare explicitly if I want to use serialization/deserialization. I've declared nothing but I use System.Xml.Serialization, newtonsoft.json and it works fine. With native toolchain, of course.
I'm using IoC container also, and it works too.

Why ? Is it normal ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to deploy the package in **release** mode yet ?

Comment: @Pratyay yes, and it works fine. But I haven't try to submit to store yet...